# How do I find all Sequence Lengths in a FASTA Dataset without using the Biopython

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta

Let's say we have a FASTA file like this:

```
>header1
ASDTWQEREWQDDSFADFASDASDQWEFQW
>header2
ASFECAERVA
>header3
ACTGQSDFWGRWTFSH
```

and this is my desired output:

```
header1 30
header2 10
header3 16
```

Please answer this question without using Biopython. I think `re.match('^>')` can be used here to distinguish the header line and other sequence lines (need to import re first) but I need some helps for the rest part to get the output. Only use python, no Biopython. Thank you!

Here is my current code:

```
import re
path='/home/try.txt'
count=0
seq=''
with open(path) as d_g:
    for line in d_g:
        if re.match('^>',line):
            count=count+1
            print('head',count)
        else:
            seq=seq+line
```

Comment: Can the sequence be multiline? Why do you want not to use BioPython? Is this an assignment? How large will be the file?

Comment: So this is homework? I can easily give you a solution, but it makes more sense that you first show us what you've tried.

Comment: After you have received answers, please don't change your question to ask something different. Instead, accept one of the answers (or post one of your own and accept that when you can) and ask a new question. (But do check for duplicates first.)

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need regular expressions for this.

```py
header = None
length = 0
with open('file.fasta') as fasta:
    for line in fasta:
        # Trim newline
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line.startswith('>'):
            # If we captured one before, print it now
            if header is not None:
                print(header, length)
                length = 0
            header = line[1:]
        else:
            length += len(line)
# Don't forget the last one
if length:
    print(header, length)
```

This uses very basic Python idioms which should be easy to pick up from any introduction to text processing in Python. Very briefly, we remember what we have seen so far, and print what we remember before starting to remember a new record (which happens when we see a header line). A common bug is forgetting to print the last record when we reach the end of the file, which of course doesn't have a new header line.

If you can guarantee that all sequences are on a single line, this could be simplified radically, but I wanted to present a general solution.

Comment: This is the best solution without using non-Python packages, and should be accepted.

Answer (score 1):

[`collections.Counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) and a simple loop with state to the rescue.

I augmented your test data to have a multi-line sequence too, just so we can tell things work right.

```
import io
import collections

# Using a stringio to emulate a file
data = io.StringIO("""
>header1
ASDTWQEREWQDDSFADFASDASDQWEFQW
DFASDASDQWEFQWASDTWQEREWQDDSFA
>header2
ASFECAERVA
>header3
>header4
ACTGQSDFWGRWTFSH
""".strip())


counter = collections.Counter()

header = None
for line in data:
    line = line.strip()  # deal with newlines
    if line.startswith(">"):
        header = line[1:]
        continue
    counter[header] += len(line)

print(counter)
```

This prints out

```
Counter({'header1': 60, 'header4': 16, 'header2': 10})
```

Comment: Fasta files can be **huge** both in terms of size and in terms of the number of sequences. I recommend to avoid storing `counter` in memory. Instead, print the sequence length as soon as you see the next fasta header.

Comment: @TimurShtatland A counter from a 200 meg FASTA file I found (apparently from a chicken spleen?) with 148197 headers has the Python process consume about 29 megabytes. That's not that bad.

Answer (score 0):

Do not reinvent the wheel. There are many specialized bioinformatics tools to handle fasta files.

For example, use [`infoseq`](http://www.sacs.ucsf.edu/Documentation/emboss/infoseq.html) utility from the [`EMBOSS`](http://emboss.sourceforge.net/) package:

```
infoseq -auto -only -name -length -noheading file.fasta
```

Prints:

```
header1        30     
header2        10     
header3        16
```

Install `EMBOSS`, for example, using [`conda`](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/install/index.html):

```
conda create --name emboss emboss
```

From the man page:

```
infoseq -help
   -only               boolean    [N] This is a way of shortening the command
                                  line if you only want a few things to be
                                  displayed. Instead of specifying:
                                  '-nohead -noname -noacc -notype -nopgc
                                  -nodesc'
                                  to get only the length output, you can
                                  specify
                                  '-only -length'
   -[no]heading        boolean    [Y] Display column headings
   -name               boolean    [@(!$(only))] Display 'name' column
   -length             boolean    [@(!$(only))] Display 'length' column
```

Comment: The question explicitly says to reinvent the wheel using Python, not BioPython.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple for loop you can use:

````
for i in f:
    if i[0] == ">":
        x = i.replace(">", "").rstrip()
    if i[0] != ">":
        y = len(i)
        print(x, y) ```
````