Count the number of lines and characters in a file separated by a specific character
I have a fasta file:
>1
AGGGTCACGTAATGCTGATCCAGTCTTGTTTTTATTTTCATTCATGTTCCCGCTCTTGCT
TTGATTCCGACTTCTAACGTTTAACCTGTGATCAGACGTTTCACTGCTCCATATTTTACG
TGTGCCTGCCGGTCATCTTGGGTAGAGTTAGCATATCC
>2
GTTTGGAAAACCTTGAGAACTTGGCTGAGCAACTAGGAGATAGGCGTATAAAGACTATCG
GCTTTGTTCTCGAAAAAATTCAATCAATTTTCGAGCATTCTTATCGCAGAATTGTTGAAT
>3
ACTCATG

Where the actual number of lines following each ">" can be thousands or even millions long. In this example, there are 158 letters (and 3 lines) following the >1, 2 lines and 120 characters after the >2, and 1 line of 7 characters after the >3.
I would like to have output to be something like:
>1
3 158
>2
2 120
>3
1 7

(format isn't critical as long as two pieces of information - the number of lines and the number of characters) is there.
I have been using a python script to split these files by the > and then count the number of lines and characters between each >. However, the files are very large and the python script takes a long time to run. Is there a simple way to do this using awk or something else in the Linux command line?

Can you add your expected output and show python script as well

"count the number of lines" in you example this is only 1 ?? (Please add some explanation on desired output, and more details on what is expected)

To clarify, the ... after "ABCXYZ" indicates that it could be arbitrarily long and over arbitrarily many lines, i.e. the intervals between each > can consist of thousands or even millions of lines.

Please use [edit] to make your question more look like what you have IRL (In Real Life),  a [mre]!   Are there really multiple lines or are they show wrapped in your editor (or on your screen)?

Hopefully the current version gives a better idea of the file structure.

Now Please add the desired output, because I did read your question multiple times, and still doe not have a clue about what it should look like. (and I hate guessing!)

Done. To remove ambiguity, I've deleted the ... following each string, though as I mentioned there can be arbitrarily many lines in the file between each >  separator.

please update the question with the python code you've tried and and an indication of any issues with the result generated by said code

@Max Why do you need the number of lines? I think that this info is usually irrelevant for fasta files such as the one you showed.

@Max To count the lengths of sequences in the fasta file, use EMBOSS package, infoseq utility: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69442590/967621

For ease of processing, we split lines in fasta files into rows of consistent size, so tallying line numbers is relevant for our specific pipeline.

Related posts: https://stackoverflow.com/q/23992646/680068 and https://www.biostars.org/p/118954/

Here's an other awk idea that handles empty sequences, empty lines and comments in FASTA files:
awk '
    /^;/ { next }
    /^>/ {
        if (substr(seq,1,1) == "\n")
             print gsub(/\n/,"",seq)-1, length(seq);
        seq = "\n";
        print;
        next
    }
    { seq = seq $0 "\n" }
    END {
        if (substr(seq,1,1) == "\n")
            print gsub(/\n/,"",seq)-1, length(seq);
    }
' file.fasta

>1
3 158
>2
2 120
>3
1 7


awk 'function doit(){ print y, length(x); y=0; x="" }
     /^>/{ if(x!=""){ doit() }; s=substr($0,2)}
     !/^>/{ x=x $0; y++ }END{ doit() }'  file1.txt


Then function doit() print the results. (and resets x and y)
/^> when a line starts with a > update s (NOTE: this value is never used!?)
!/^>/ when a line does not start with a '>' add that line to the variable x, and increment y.

test:
$ cat file
>1
AGGGTCACGTAATGCTGATCCAGTCTTGTTTTTATTTTCATTCATGTTCCCGCTCTTGCT
TTGATTCCGACTTCTAACGTTTAACCTGTGATCAGACGTTTCACTGCTCCATATTTTACG
TGTGCCTGCCGGTCATCTTGGGTAGAGTTAGCATATCC
>2
GTTTGGAAAACCTTGAGAACTTGGCTGAGCAACTAGGAGATAGGCGTATAAAGACTATCG
GCTTTGTTCTCGAAAAAATTCAATCAATTTTCGAGCATTCTTATCGCAGAATTGTTGAAT

$ awk 'function doit(){ print y, length(x); y=0; x="" }/^>/{ if(x!=""){ doit() }; s=substr($0,2)}!/^>/{ x=x $0; y++ }END{ doit() }'  file
3 158
3 120


One awk idea:
awk '
function print_sums() {
    if (linecnt>0)                     # if linecnt > 0 then ...
       print linecnt,charcnt           # print current counters
    linecnt = charcnt = 0              # reset counters
}
/^>/ { print_sums()                    # print counters for previous block
       print                           # print current line
       next                            # skip to next line of input
     }    
     { linecnt++                       # increment line counter
       charcnt += length($0)           # increment character counter
     }
END  { print_sums() }                  # print counters for last block
' input.dat 

This generates:
>1
3 158
>2
2 120
>3
1 7


If you change if (linecnt>0) print linecnt,charcnt to if (NR>1) print linecnt+0,charcnt+0 then it'd produce counts even for cases where there were 2 consecutive >  lines. As written in that case it'd print the > line but then no counts before the next > line. idk if the OP can have that in their input, of course, but if they can then getting counts of 0 output like it'd be more desirable than a > line with nothing after it.

$ awk '
    /^>/{ a[i+=1]=$0; next }
    { b[i]+=1; c[i]+=length($0) }
    END{ for(j=1; j<=i; j++) printf "%s\n%d %d\n", a[j], b[j], c[j] } 
' file
>1
3 158
>2
2 120
>3
1 7


This is by far not a complete answer, but using grep -n you can show the line number of the line where the > character appears.
From that point on, you can start using awk to perform calculations on those numbers:
Prompt>grep -n ">" file1.txt
1:>1
3:>2
5:>3

Prompt>grep -n ">" file1.txt | awk -F ":" '{print $1}'
1
3
5

...

there is no need to take small steps, (but it is a bit unclear what desired output should look like).  Combining the 2 steps + the awk step could look like: awk '/^>/{ s=substr($0,2)}!/^>/{ print substr($0,s,1) }'  file, to print the position based on the number given after >

I would exploit GNU AWK for this task following way, let file.txt content be
>1
AGGGTCACGTAATGCTGATCCAGTCTTGTTTTTATTTTCATTCATGTTCCCGCTCTTGCT
TTGATTCCGACTTCTAACGTTTAACCTGTGATCAGACGTTTCACTGCTCCATATTTTACG
TGTGCCTGCCGGTCATCTTGGGTAGAGTTAGCATATCC
>2
GTTTGGAAAACCTTGAGAACTTGGCTGAGCAACTAGGAGATAGGCGTATAAAGACTATCG
GCTTTGTTCTCGAAAAAATTCAATCAATTTTCGAGCATTCTTATCGCAGAATTGTTGAAT
>3
ACTCATG

then
awk 'BEGIN{RS=">[0-9]+\n";FPAT="[ACGT]";ORS=""}NR==1{print RT;next}{printf "%s %s\n%s",gsub(/\n/,""),NF,RT}' file.txt

gives output
>1
3 158
>2
2 120
>3
1 7

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK that rows are separated by > followed by one-or-more (+) digits ([0-9]) followed by newline, that field consist of one characters from following set ACGT and output row separator is empty string. For 1st row (which is empty string before >1) I just print row terminator (RT) for all other I use printf to output number of newlines character (which I count using gsub String function), number of fields (which is number of characters from set) and row terminator (which is >2 then >3) in desired format. Observe I do not add newline at end, as it is already present in row terminator, as row separator has newline at end.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)
